# VS2012 doesn't include winres.h any more?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

After installing VS2012, I can't find winres.h under folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC". What happen to VS2012 and why remove this header file?

By the way, in VS2010, winres.h locates in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include"

Comment: Are you using a non-Express version of VS2012?

Comment: Yes, I am using Ultimate 2012, and the version is 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is part of the Windows SDK now and since VS2012 the SDK location is different, it's now called a 'Kit' and is found in Program Files/Windows Kits. Sepcifically you can find winres.h in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um
```

Comment: Thanks @stijn, then seems I have to install windows 8 sdk.

Comment: are you sure? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606739/windows-kit-8-0-and-visual-studio-2012-are-they-shipped-together

Comment: Aha, this is shipped with VS2012 by default. Got it, and Thanks again.